# compare two data frames of different data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to compare two data frames of different lengths and different data types.

df1 ['num'] is of type 'Object' and the column 'num' contains integers and string objects.

| num |
| --- |
| 100899 |
| 1980903 |
| AB347980 |
| RT198090 |

df2['num'] is of type 'float'

| num |
| --- |
| 100899.0 |
| 1980903.0 |
| 937974938.0 |
| 2837982.0 |

This is what i have tried so far;

1. Converting df2 to integers and then comparing it to df1 using pd.concat()
   2.converting df2 to objects and then comparing it to df1 using pd.merge. when i try this method the numbers don't match because one is of type float and other of integer type within the object data type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

If you are sure that your entire column is filled with number values and no strings, you can do this:

```
df['num'] = df['num'].map('{:.0f}'.format)
```

If they are all number values, with some NaN values, you can do this:

```
df['num'] = df['num'].map('{:.0f}'.format,na_action = 'ignore')
```

If you have strings then it will error out. One option if this is the case is to use `pd.to_numeric()`

```
df['num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['num'],errors = 'coerce').map('{:.0f}'.format,na_action = 'ignore').fillna(df['num'])
```

Comment: there are certain null values in the column though